# implement data transfer issue according to viewbinding

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

The code I wrote is not working because viewbinding is not suitable. I got some help from my friend but I still couldn't do the application please help me my application is interrupted

```
/*MainActivity*/
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var _binding: ActivityMainBinding?=null//
    private val binding
    get()=_binding!!

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        _binding=ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.apply{ //5.işlemimiz ;)
            editText

        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
    
    fun aktiviteDegistir (view:View){

        val kullaniciVerisi = editText.text.toString()

        val intent = Intent(applicationContext,IkinciActivity::class.java)
     
        intent.putExtra("yollananVeri",kullaniciVerisi)
        
        startActivity(intent)//activiteyi başlatım güzel yer
    }



/*Activity2*/
val intent = intent//intent 
    val alinanVeri = intent.getStringExtra("yollananVeri") 
    textView2.text = alinanVeri
```

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var _binding: ActivityMainBinding?=null//3.islemimiz
    private val binding
    get()=_binding!!

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {//4.işlemiiz
        _binding=ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.apply{ //5.işlemimiz ;)
            editText

        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
```

After adding this code, I waited for the messages to go away, but they didn't.
my application will write something about this to the editText button will be pressed then it needs to come to the textview part in the other activity

Answer (score 0):

you are following approach, that is used to bind in fragment binding. The problem is that you are setting the binding data but not connecting it with the content view. for better approach in activity view binding just the same for more cleaner activity binding.

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    private lateinit var binder : ActivityMainBinding
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binder = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binder.root)
        
        viewImpl()
    }

    /**you view calls...
     * like button.setonclick() and all UI related interactions...
     */ 
    private fun viewImpl() {
        binder.run {
            //here...
        }
    }
}
```

In here I have created binding `lateinit var` for activity binder which will be initialise when `binder = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)` and then using that binder reference for setting my content view as `setContentView(binder.root)`.

Happy Coding ✌️.